# Error saving components to database with fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here is my object and mapping:

```
 public class candleStim
{
    public virtual int       Id            { get; set; }
    public virtual int       candleNumber  { get; set; } //the number of the candle from the data set, should correspond with number of minutes into testing on 1 min candles
    public virtual DateTime  date          { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   open          { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   high          { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   low           { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   close         { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EMA> EMAs          { get; set; } //List all EMAs calculated.
    public virtual List<SMA> SMAs          { get; set; }
}

    public class candleStimMap : ClassMap<candleStim>
    {
        public candleStimMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);

            Map(x => x.candleNumber);
            Map(x => x.date);
            Map(x => x.open);
            Map(x => x.high);
            Map(x => x.low);
            Map(x => x.close);



            HasMany<SMA>(x => x.SMAs)
                .Component(c =>
                    {
                        c.Map(x => x.SimpleMovingAverage);
                        c.Map(x => x.periods);
                    }).AsSet();


            HasMany<EMA>(x => x.EMAs)
              .Component(c =>
              {
                  c.Map(x => x.ExponentialMovingAverage);
                  c.Map(x => x.periods);
              }).AsSet();
            Table("candle_Simulation");


        } //end public candleStimMap()
```

Here is my current attempt at saving (which fails)

```
     foreach (candleStim c in calculatedCandles)
            {
                using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
                {

                    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {

                        candleStim cc = new candleStim();
                        cc.date = c.date;
                        cc.open = c.open;
                        cc.high = c.high;
                        cc.low = c.low;
                        cc.close = c.close;

 //The below 2 lines are where the problem arises
//if these are standard objects, no errors show up
                        cc.EMAs = c.EMAs;
                        cc.SMAs = c.SMAs;


                        session.Save(c);
                        transaction.Commit();

                    }

                }
                counter++;

            }
```

The error msg:{"Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[Midas_FOREX_Engine.Indicators.SMA]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Midas_FOREX_Engine.Indicators.SMA]'."}

So I've got a mismatch of list types. How would I make a list of the NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet type and save the values?

The only fields Im saving to the database from the SMA-EMA is a decimal of the value and an integer of the number of periods.

Thank you!!

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a hint as to what these errors are? It's too early in the morning for me to fire up my mind reading abilities..

Comment: please share the error message with us fluently ;)

Comment: what are `EMA` and `SMA`? How does the entity and the mapping of those classes look like?

Comment: Isnt the mapping for EMA and SMA handled by the component call above? Because the only fields from them that are saved to the database are the average value and the periods variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you map a `HasMany` property to `AsSet`, you should use an `ISet` type on it.

So you property will become like:

```
public virtual Iesi.Collections.ISet<EMA> EMAs          { get; set; }
```

I strongly recommend you to read this NHibernate docs chapter (if you still didn't).

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-persistent

It will clarify you about how to choose the best property type / mapping to your `one-to-many` situation.